# Choosing diagonals in an $n$-gon

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n>3$ be odd. Find the least value of $k$ such that in any convex $n$-gon, the sum of the lengths of $k$ arbitrarily chosen diagonals is at least as large as the sum of the lengths of the other unchosen diagonals.

I have a bound $k\geq\left(\binom{n}{2}-n\right)-\tfrac{1}{2}(n-3)+1$. This is because we can take a "water droplet" shape, with $n-1$ points arranged along a semicircle, and the last point arbitrarily far away. Then effectively the only diagonals that matter are those $n-3$ diagonals joining our far away point to the others. Clearly, we need to take more than half of these $n-3$ diagonals, and this gives the claimed bound.

However, I have no idea whether this bound is tight/can be improved.

Comment: A good method of checking is whether it holds for any $n$-sided regular polygon.

Comment: Hi, @MalayTheDynamo, the bound trivially holds for a **regular** polygon. I'm wondering whether the bound is tight, or if there exist $n$-gons for which the value of $k$ needs to be higher.